# take only one record of select

Tags: sql, db2

I need to fetch only first record (because I need last date) of resultset, at the moment I have this resultset from this sql tring:

```
SELECT BCACC,FLDAT
FROM ANAGEFLF
ORDER BY FLDAT DESC
```

and I see this record:

```
A.M.T. AUTOTRASPORTI SRL        20080220
A.M.T. AUTOTRASPORTI SRL        20080123
A.M.T. AUTOTRASPORTI SRL        20070731
APOFRUIT ITALIA                 20080414
APOFRUIT ITALIA                 20080205
APOFRUIT ITALIA                 20071210
APOFRUIT ITALIA                 20070917
APOFRUIT ITALIA                 20070907
```

now I need to take only one record (first) for every BCACC, I would take this resultset:

```
A.M.T. AUTOTRASPORTI SRL        20080220
APOFRUIT ITALIA                 20080414
```

I've just try group it for BCACC but I receive an sql error, I'm workin on DB2 ibmI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming they are the only fields involved, you can just do a `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT
  BCACC,
  MAX(FLDAT) AS FLDAT
FROM
  ANAGEFLF
GROUP BY
  BCACC
```

If, however, you have other fields that you need, then you just join this back of the table as a sub-query...

```
SELECT
  ANAGEFLF.*
FROM
  ANAGEFLF
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT
    BCACC,
    MAX(FLDAT) AS FLDAT
  FROM
    ANAGEFLF
  GROUP BY
    BCACC
)
  AS map
    ON  map.BCACC = ANAGEFLF.BCACC
    AND map.FLDAT = ANAGEFLF.FLDAT
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select BCACC, max(FLDAT)
from ANAGEFLF
group by BCACC
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer for the first part of your question "I need to fetch only first record of resultset" is:

```
SELECT BCACC,FLDAT
FROM ANAGEFLF
ORDER BY FLDAT DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
```

But the global question was another, about how to fix a query to only retrieve the correct values.

Comment: Stop being picky about grammar.  Based on the example input set and example output set, it's clear enough as to what the OP meant.